# main.css broke after changing @import to link

Tags: css

I have a question with the Optimizing CSS Delivery, please.

I changed my main.css from

```
@import url(bootstrap.css);@import url(../rs-plugin/css/settings.css);@import url(responsiveslides.css);@import url(prettyPhoto.css);@import url(flexslider.css);@import url(style.css);@import url(rev-settings.css);@import url(../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css);@import url(colors/red.css);@import url(switcher.css);
```

to

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='bootstrap.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../rs-plugin/css/settings.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='responsiveslides.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='flexslider.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='rev-settings.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='colors/red.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='switcher.css' />
```

My Google Page Speed score imporoved drastically but my index.html is not loading with css.

If I change the main.css back to those bunch of import statements then everything works fine.

I am using http://themeforest.net/item/truehost-responsive-html-5-hosting-template/5828966 tenplate , if that helps!

Comment: I would check for syntax errors and typos.

Comment: of the css file names in the link statements? I'm sure they are the correct spellings.

Comment: I don't know.  I bet the paths are wrong.  Did you change the paths to be relative to the html file instead of the css?  Or do you really have plugins stored below the html root of your files?